# Nautilus FTP forgets my home directory

Tags: nautilus, ftp

I'm using Nautilus to work with an ftp server that logs me straight into a home directory. (that is, connecting to ftp://foo.com/ actually logs me into ftp://foo.com/home/vashti/) However, I'm seeing some weird behaviour as follows:

1. Nautilus isn't aware that I log in to that directory - it thinks /home/vashti is the root directory. The server is not chrooted and I have full access to files higher up the tree - Nautilus just can't see them.
2. I can add a / (connecting to ftp://foo.com//home/vashti/) to make the home directory register, but if I close the Nautilus window and reopen it, the connected server has again forgotten that /home/vashti is not /, and I can't access the higher level directories.
3. I also can't connect to ftp://foo.com// to force connecting to the root directory - that just connects to /home/vashti.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong? Are there bugs? Is there anything else I could try? I had a go with curlftpfs first, but it seemed to be flaky at best.